# Letter partially disappearing when exporting text using CairoPNG

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I'm trying to construct a chart using ggplot which I am then saving to PNG image using the Cairo package's CairoPNG function.

The problem is that the resulting image file seems to be missing chunks of the letter J on the x axis. This is a bit of an issue when I'm using month name as the x axis label.

This only seems to happen when the text size is set to a whole number (such as 12). If I set it to 11.5 or 12.5 then the letters display fine.

So, I can fix it by altering the font size but it feels like a bit of a hack. Does anyone know why it's behaving like this?

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library("Cairo")

# Set chart values
line.width = 1
font.size = 12

# Generate some random data
start.date <- as.Date("2011-07-01")
x.month <-seq.Date(start.date, by = "month", length.out = 24)
end.date <- max(x.month)


x.value <- rnorm(24,mean=50,sd=2)

# Combine into dataframe
x.data <- data.frame(
  "Month" = x.month,
  "Value" = x.value
  )

# Build chart
p <- ggplot(data=x.data, aes(Month, Value)) + geom_line(size=line.width)
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + ggtitle("Test Chart\n")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(40, 60))
p <- p + scale_x_date(limits=c(start.date+20,end.date-20), breaks = "1 month",labels = date_format("%b-%y"))
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=font.size),
                axis.text.y=element_text(size=font.size),
                axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                axis.title.y=element_blank())

# Export chart
CairoPNG("c:\\temp\\temp1.png", width=500, height = 250)
p
dev.off()
```

---

**Edit 1**
I tried the following code suggested by baptiste but the letters seem to come through fine:

```
CairoPNG("test.png"); grid::grid.text("The disappearing J"); dev.off()
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2**

Issue isolated courtesy of baptiste. It really doesn't seem to like rotating capital Js!

```
CairoPNG("c:\\temp\\test.png",width=60, height=300); grid::grid.text("Rejoicefully Juxtaposing Jelly with Jam\nabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", rot=90); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest you test the letter J on its own; this probably has nothing to do with ggplot2. Try `CairoPNG("test.png"); grid::grid.text("The disappearing J"); dev.off()`.

Comment: Hmm, I've updated my question with the results but that doesn't replicate the error. I wonder if it's a combination of the rotation of the text with CairoPNG. If I use the basic png function then I don't get the same problem.

Comment: and if you rotate the letter, ie `grid.text("J", rot=90)`?

Comment: Question updated, so this pins it on Cairo it would seem. I'll update the title too!

Comment: could be the font, try changing it. Also see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gnuplot/MaZ4eGK2bbg which seems similar

Comment: That's interesting, I wonder why it recovers at different font sizes. I can't even get the font family to change, have tried using the family argument to set it to serif but it just seems to get ignored.